# How to extract lines from a blob of text instead of characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code snippet prints out each character on a new line instead of printing out each line.  I think this is a simple fix but I can't remember how this is done:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.zillow.com/<rest of url doesn\'t matter>'
    r = s.get(url)
    for line in r.text:
        print(line)
```

I know I could use regex to print when the end of a line is reached but figured there was a much cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `splitlines`:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.zillow.com/<rest of url doesn\'t matter>'
    r = s.get(url)
    for line in str(r.text).splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I'm rusty and totally forgot about that method!

Comment: @SamDillard Happy to help, :-), 